# Criteria for an element being in a set

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Currently working on the next big thing in mathematics (also known as 3rd Year discrete algebra... yuck), so I'll likely post a stack of questions up here (Since our lecturer has recently been described as "unhelpful").

Today's query - One that I seem to not be able to find a huge amount of specific info on: I have:

$\boldsymbol{G}$ a group. $\boldsymbol{H}$ is a subgroup of G, and
A is a subset of G. We are given the following statement that is the
first part to an equivalence proof:

$Ag = A$

For $g\,\epsilon\, H$. My question - does this imply that $g$
is also in $A$? My thoughts are that if I have a multiplication
of two elements and end up with the set, this must imply that those
elements are contained within the set. My only hesitation is that
$A$ is a subset, and hence does not neccessarily have to be
closed under multiplication. However, if for any $g$ in $G$
I get the $A$ back again, doesn't this imply that all
$g$ in $H$ is also in $A$? (And hence it also follows
that $H$ is contained within $A$?)

Comment: Is $A$ only a subset or is it a subgroup? If it is a subgroup, then $1 \in A$ and so $g = 1 \cdot g \in A g = A$ for all $g \in H$.

Comment: A is only a subset, sorry, I mistyped that last bit. That's my only point of hesitation. The fact that it is a subset implies that it might not be closed, but then if I multiply elements of H by A and get A back again - does it follow that H is contained in A?

Answer (score 1):

Given a group $G$, a subgroup $H \subseteq G$ and a subset $A \subseteq G$ such that $A g = A$ for all $g \in H$, you have $H \subseteq A$ if and only if $1 \in A$. First, if $H \subseteq A$ then $1 \in H \subseteq A$, so $1 \in A$. Secondly, if $1 \in A$ then $g = 1 \cdot g \in A g = A$ for all $g \in H$, hence $H \subseteq A$.

At last, note that there are subsets $A$ of $G$ which are invariant under multiplication with elements of $H$ and do not contain $1$ (for instance the empty set).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Here are some counter examples:

1. $H = \{1\}$
2. $G=H$ the integers. $A$ the even numbers

Comment: I do not understand either example here. If $G$ is the integers then the operation must be addition. Therefore, when we write $Ag$ we mean the set $\{a+g; a\in A\}$, and if $A$ is the even numbers then this is equal to $A$ if and only if $g\in A$ (because the even numbers form a subgroup of $G$). For your first example. is $A$ just any subset? Or any not containing the identity?